# removing elements from pandas dataframe iterator prior to loading to json (to_json)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove email and userid from the data_json string as it's extracted out prior and i don't want these fields listed twice, working python script:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/keys/json_poc.txt')
project_id = 'myproject'
bq_conn = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials,project=project_id)


 # setup sql query
bq_sql = ("""
select email , userid, * except (email , userid) from dataset.usertable
""")

# load up dataframe
df = bq_conn.query(bq_sql).to_dataframe()

# iterate over rows
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    
    # pull out email and userid from df
    email = df.loc[i]['email']
    userid = df.loc[i]['userid']
    
    # build json data fields for iterable
    data_json = df.loc[i].to_json(orient="columns") # remove fields
    
    # json format {"email": "email@yahoo.com","dataFields": {},"userId": "99999"}
    final_json = '{"email": "' + email + '","dataFields": ' + data_json + ',"userId": "' + userid + '"}'
    r = requests.request(method="POST", url=url, headers=headers, data=final_json)
    print('added: ' + email)
```

the output from the API (GET) looks something like this:

```
b'{"user":{"email":"email@yahoo.com","dataFields":{"email":"email@yahoo.com","userId":"99999","StateofResidence":"CA",......,"categoryid":99},"userId":"99999"}}'
```

Above you can see that the email and userid fields are listed twice. We will have about 500 attributes for each user so it's not practical to build the json string by manually extracting the elements (plus I want to be able to add columns to the source table without updating the python).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, just need to change the following:

```
def myconverter(o):
if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
    return o.__str__()

bq_sql = ("""select email , userid, * except (email , userid) from dataset.usertable 
""")

df = bq_conn.query(bq_sql).to_dataframe()

for i, row in df.iterrows():

    payload_dict = {"email": row["email"], "dataFields": row.drop(labels=['userid', 'email']).to_dict(), "userid": row["userid"]} 

    json_payload = json.dumps(payload_dict, default = myconverter) #cast datetime
    
    r = requests.request(method="POST", url=url, headers=headers, data=json_payload)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
```